# How to distribute XPCOM component via XPI for FireFox 3?

Tags: firefox, xpcom, xpi

I wrote an XPCOM component and an extension that uses it. XPCOM loads arbitrary DLL for its purposes.

How can I include XPCOM and DLL into XPI package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find absolute path to my DLL via IExtensionManager and IInstallLocation, then load it via LoadLibrary().

1. put DLL near XPCOM in my.xpi/components/
2. figure out the path to extension via IExtensionManager and IInstallLocation
3. LoadLibrary()
4. profit

Answer (score 0):

XPI is basically a zip file, which includes the DLL, among other things
See 
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Creating_XPI_Installer_Modules

Comment: yes, but i can't find the way to load DLL from XPCOM.
now i am struggling to get a path to extension directory to use in LoadLibrary call.

Comment: What is your environment? Win/UNix/Mac, Firefox/Thunderbird?
THe paths to extension directories depend on that.

Comment: I figure with IExtensionManager and IInstallLocation, you can neglect environment differences.